# Powershell compare text files and write difference lines to a new file

Tags: powershell

**File 1.txt**

```
Abc
Def
Xyz
```

**File 2.txt**

```
Xyz
Def
```

Abc is not found in file 2 when file 1 is compared against file 2, So want to write Abc to a new file diff.txt.

**diff.txt**

```
Abc
```

I saw many posts using compare-object but those are not producing outputs like what my requirement was. I am new to Powershell

Comment: Please share what code have you tried and what's the not desired output from your current attempts?

Comment: Are you looking for the lines from `File1.txt` that don't exist in `File2.txt`? Or are you looking for differences both ways?

Comment: Also are those line numbers apart of the file?

Comment: should it also catch if lines are on different numbers. Example Say File1 Abc is on line 5 and in File2 Abc is on line 1. Should that count as a difference?

Comment: No @ArcSet, If Abc is found anywhere in file 2 then no need of that line in diff.txt

Comment: Line numbers are not part of file. Just for explanation. Yes, I am looking for lines of file1 that doesn't exist in file 2.@RoadRunner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding you want to write all lines from `File1.txt` than don't exist in `File2.txt`.

We can use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) to read both files into an array of strings, and use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) to filter lines from `File1.txt` that are `-notin` `File2.txt`. We can then output the differences to a new file with [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7).

```
$file2 = Get-Content -Path .\File2.txt

$diff = Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notin $file2}

$diff | Out-File -FilePath diff.txt
```

However, for larger files, doing a **O(N)** linear search with `-notin` can be expensive. Instead, we can use a [`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) for constant time **O(1)** lookups using [`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

For the below example I use [`System.Linq.Enumerable.ToHashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset?view=netframework-4.8) to create this hash set, which uses the array of strings from `Get-Content` as an [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8).

```
$file2HashSet = [Linq.Enumerable]::ToHashSet(
  [string[]] (Get-Content -Path .\File2.txt),
  [StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
)

$diff = Get-Content -Path .\File1.txt | Where-Object {-not $file2HashSet.Contains($_)}

$diff | Out-File -FilePath diff.txt
```

**diff.txt**

```
Abc
```

Comment: I tried the first answer and it worked. One thing first when I used the code I entered the path along with the HYPHEN that mentioned in answer. It didn't work so I removed HYPHEN before the path and tried. It works.

EDIT: I meant when I had paths as -E:\**\file1.txt it didn't work. So I had given path without "-"

Comment: I had added an EDIT in my first comment to your answer

Comment: At max I have 1000 lines in file 1 & 100 lines in file 2. So which of your answer will be resource efficient for me?

Comment: @GowthamSarathy If the second file only has 100 lines, the first solution shouldn't be bad. Although I recommend the second solution in any case, since it will perform well for any size of file.

Comment: @GowthamSarathy Try both approaches with `Measure-Command`. That will tell you the performance difference.

Comment: Sure. Will try and comment on it